# Facebook Like Button Confirmation Page Says "The Page You Requested Was Not Found"

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Just finished putting a like button on a website I was working on. Everything was working fine, but while testing, I guess I like and unliked too many times and got put on the click blacklist. That would be fine, except that the confirm button always says "The Page You Requested Was Not Found". Used the url linter and everything seems to be fine. I've double and triple checked my meta tags and iframe. I can't figure it out! Please help! Here's the website:

http://melissy.com/html/index.php

Here's the object properties of the page:

g:url:  http://melissy.com/html/index.php
og:type:    website
og:title:   Melissa Davidson
og:image:   (this is not blank, was shown as a picture on the debugger)
og:description: Southern California artist Melissa Davidsons official website. Includes painting and photo galleries, as well as event and contact information.
og:site_name:   Melissa Davidson

And the Open Graph Metadata

```
meta property="og:title" content="Melissa Davidson" 
meta property="og:type" content="website" 
meta property="og:url" content="http://melissy.com/html/index.php"
meta property="og:image" content="(removed)"
meta property="og:site_name" content="Melissa Davidson" 
meta property="fb:admins" content="(took this out for security purposes)" 
meta property="og:description" content="Southern California artist Melissa Davidsons official website. Includes painting and photo galleries, as well as event and contact information."
```

I am looking forward to your advice. Thanks!

Comment: If you think this you're encountering a bug, you should file it in Facebook's bug tracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/
In this case, your markup is fine and the debugger accepts the page, so it's likely a bug

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Just posting in case anybody else has this problem. I created the like button on the facebook like button generator:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

When I generated the code, I picked "standard" layout. Later, I decided to change to "box-count". I changed the appropriate variable in the iframe url embedded on my page. All the code was correct. However, the button does not work unless it is set to "standard". I guess when you create the button on Facebook they create some kind of record which becomes permanently linked to the url